# Extract method name and add it for logger as first line of method

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a requirement in which Java method name needs to be added in logger in the first line of the method.

I am trying the following approach.

1. Get lines with keyword `private`, `protected` or `public` and the character `(`. This will identify the method definition.
2. Extract the method name
3. When method name is found, add a new line after 2 lines, and add

   ```
   Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_name, "name of the method")
   ```

   where "name of the method" is one extracted in step 2.

I have tried the below code.

```
#! /bin/bash

arr=($(grep -E 'public|private|protected' DataServiceImpl.java | grep "(" | awk '{print$3}' | awk -F'(' '{print $1}'))

for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; ++i )); do
   sed "/${arr[$i]}(/{N;a Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,\"${arr[$i]}\");
   }" DataServiceImpl.java > changedText.txt && mv changedText.txt DataServiceImpl.java
done
```

It works fine. But the problem is it inserts the new line and `Logger.add` after the calling line also.

For instance, if I have a method `public String getProtocol()`, it adds the line

```
Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,"getProtocol")
```

as first line of the method definition. It also adds it in the place where `getProtocol()` is called.

How can this be avoided? Is there a way we can do something like this?

```
#! /bin/bash

arr=($(grep -E 'public|private|protected' DataServiceImpl.java | grep "("))

for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; ++i )); do

//search for match of array element. This would result in complete line till (
//If match found, add a line after two lines and add the below code.
//Extract 3rd column of array element. In public String getProtocol, we will get getProtocol
//Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME, "extracted column")
done
```

Sample Java Class:

```
public class DataServiceImpl
   {
     public String getProtocol()
     {
        return "https";
     }
     public String buildUrl()
     {
       String url = getProtocol()+"://www.google.com";
       return url;
     }
}
```

*Expected Result:*

```
public class DataServiceImpl
   {
     public String getProtocol()
     {
        Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,"getProtocol");
        return "https";
     }
     public String buildUrl()
     {
       Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,"buildUrl");
       String url = getProtocol()+"://www.google.com";
       return url;
     }
}
```

Also it would be helpful if there is a way to specify that the line `Logger.add` should be added below `{` and one space after the alignment of `{`.
Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of your input file that we can use to test our solutions. Also show the output you would expect from that example.

Comment: Edited the question with sample class and the expected result.

Comment: The indenting is not consistent, can you please correct it?

Answer (score 0):

We shall employ GNU sed in extended regex mode (to make the regex writing tractable, to some extent):
P. S: This is not a parser so expect some corner cases to trip up sometimes.

```
$ sed -re '
    /^\s*(public|private|protected)\s.*[(]/!b
    h;s/\S+/\n/2;s/.*\n\s+//;s/[(].*//



  s/.*/Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,"&");/
    x;n;n;x;G
    s/.*\n(\s*).*/\1&/
' file.java
```

Method:
Isolate the line of interest. Then get the method name and decorate it with the required logging terminology. After that skip two lines and print.

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler, clearer, more portable, etc, with awk, e.g. with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), gensub(), and \s/\S shorthand:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/(private|protected|public).*\s(\S+)\s*\(/,a) {
    methodName = a[2]
    lineNr = NR+2
}
NR == lineNr {
    indent = gensub(/\S.*/,"",1)
    printf "%sLogger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,\"%s\");\n", indent, methodName
    lineNr = 0
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
public class DataServiceImpl
   {
     public String getProtocol()
     {
        Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,"getProtocol");
        return "https";
     }
     public String buildUrl()
     {
       Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,"buildUrl");
       String url = getProtocol()+"://www.google.com";
       return url;
     }
}
```

or using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/(private|protected|public).*\(/ {
    methodName = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]]*\(.*/,"",methodName)
    sub(/.*(private|protected|public).*[[:space:]]/,"",methodName)
    lineNr = NR+2
}
NR == lineNr {
    indent = $0
    sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",indent)
    printf "%sLogger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,\"%s\");\n", indent, methodName
    lineNr = 0
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
public class DataServiceImpl
   {
     public String getProtocol()
     {
        Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,"getProtocol");
        return "https";
     }
     public String buildUrl()
     {
       Logger.add(Constants.METHOD_NAME,"buildUrl");
       String url = getProtocol()+"://www.google.com";
       return url;
     }
}
```